# Failed to create user control, constructor not found

Tags: vb.net

I have a user control called "Grid." I had a couple of problems with a line of code (to do with grid) in the designer in my form disappearing every so often. However I just copied and pasted it back in from an older backup and it worked fine, so as it wasn't especially bothering me and I had more important things to do I left it. I have just tried to put a grid onto a form from the toolbox and I got this error:

[image]

Can anyone help me out? If I have missed anything or you need more information I should be around to respond quickly.

Edit: I have just fiddled around a bit and this is a problem common to all my user controls

Cheers - Martin

Edit: Thought it may be useful to include the designer for grid.

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Grid
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

'UserControl overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'Grid
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch
    Me.Name = "Grid"
    Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(450, 450)
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Please remember to mark my answer as accepted _if it solved your problem_. Accepting an answer is done by pressing the tick/check mark on the left of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when you write your own constructor for the control. The designer can only create an instance of a control if it has got a parameterless constructor. So if you've added a custom constructor with parameters then the designer won't be able to recognize that.

To fix it, just add a constructor with no parameters anywhere in your control and you should be good to go:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    'Do other stuff here if necessary.
End Sub
```

Comment: What if it was intentional that the UserControl's constructor has parameters.  Design wise, maybe you shouldn't be able to create the control without providing it something it needs.  In this case, here's what I did to solve the problem.  It turns out that adding a private constructor works as well.

`
partial class MyControl : UserControl
    {
        #region Designer
        private MyControl() {InitializeComponent();} // For Designer only
        #endregion
        
        public MyControl(RequiredData data)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
`

Comment: @Robear There's no issue in having a control with a parameterized constructor, but if you want to be able to add it through the designer you must _also_ have a parameterless one (both can exist simultaneously). It's interesting that you found that adding a private constructor works, but if you _"shouldn't be able to create the control without providing it something it needs"_ then the private constructor kinda defeats that.

Comment: @Vincent Visual:  This solution was useful to me because it then allowed me to drag the UserControl onto another control's design surface.  But in thinking about what you said, you're right.  If the control can't be created without a parameter, VS **should** prevent you from dragging it onto another control.  It's only important that the control's own design surface work in lieu of a parameter-less constructor, which VS does make work.

Comment: @Vincent Visual: Actually, the private constructor does have a use.  Imagine that at runtime you want a side panel to start out hidden.  But at design time, it's useful to have it visible.  So developers know (visually that it's there) when working on the project.  The private constructor allows this for design purposes.  Then at runtime, in the window constructor, you can remove the user control and hide it.  When it needs to be displayed at runtime, you recreate it (using the required parameter constructor) and then show it.